# Gson - Remove null from Array

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I understand that gson by default does not serialise null fields. However, it does serialise null objects in a JsonArray. What I want to do is get gson to remove all such null objects from all arrays. Any ideas on what the "proper" way to solve this problem is? I'd rather avoid having to write a custom serialiser for lists that will simply remove null from the JsonArray.

Comment: Why do you need it? Skipping null fields is justified since they can be deserialized back by a unique key regardless the order. Arrays are positional data structures and, having nulls removed, the array indices will be shifted to the left, thus making deserialization to the equivalent object impossible. It sounds like a sort of data loss.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv in my client-server scenario I am trying to hide as much unnecessary information (such as a null objects) from the client as possible. Array indices being updated is not an issue at all.

Comment: Then you have either prepare an array without nulls on the server side (and it seems to match your question the best), or filter out array null elements at the client side. Serializers and deserializers should not modify serialized/deserialized objects in principle.